# how to write the Max of this function / How can i use Max[]

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, homework, maximum

Hi every one I really need your help in this question write the function in the picture

[image: i know how to find it analytically but i don't know how to make a code of this fu]nction in Mathematica because I need to make graph...  ?? could anyone help me ?

I'd appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how to calculate I(A,E_i) for a value of i?

Comment: @bill s  i just modified the post, you find its expression in the photo

Comment: Hi; That link is blank on my browser.

Comment: Why not write it in Mathematica? Once you do that, I'm sure someone will help you plot and take the Max.

Comment: @bobbym I(A,E) =Max[I(A,Ei] with i=0,......,m i want to write this function in Mathematica ,

Comment: @ 
@bill s   Yes i have already written the I(A,E_i)  on mathematica but I don'tt know how i can put it here

Comment: Look around this site. Almost every question has code listings. Do it that way.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  It is recommended that you browse [the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site). Once read the edit window help button `?` gives quick reminders of that material. To remove from the screen, click `?` again.